# Rvest not recognizing css selector

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape this website:

http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/result_home.sd#resultDay=2015-12-26&meetingId=18&isFullMeeting=true

through the `rvest` package in R.

Unfortunately it seems that `rvest` doesn't recognize the nodes through the CSS selector.

For example if I try to extract the information in the header of every table (Grade, Prize, Distance), whose CSS selector is ".black" and I run this code:

```
URL <- read_html("http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/result_home.sd#resultDay=2015-12-26&meetingId=18&isFullMeeting=true")
nodes<-html_nodes(URL, ".black")
```

nodes comes out to be a null list, so it's not scraping anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's making an XHR request to generate the HTML. Try this (which should also make it easier to automate the data capture):

```
library(httr)
library(xml2)
library(rvest)

res <- GET("http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/result_by_meeting_full.sd",
           query=list(r_date="2015-12-26",
                      meeting_id=18))

doc <- read_html(content(res, as="text"))

html_nodes(doc, ".black")
## {xml_nodeset (56)}
##  [1] <span class="black">A9</span>
##  [2] <span class="black">£61</span>
##  [3] <span class="black">470m</span>
##  [4] <span class="black">-30</span>
##  [5] <span class="black">H2</span>
##  [6] <span class="black">£105</span>
##  [7] <span class="black">470m</span>
##  [8] <span class="black">-30</span>
##  [9] <span class="black">A7</span>
## [10] <span class="black">£61</span>
## [11] <span class="black">470m</span>
## [12] <span class="black">-30</span>
## [13] <span class="black">A5</span>
## [14] <span class="black">£66</span>
## [15] <span class="black">470m</span>
## [16] <span class="black">-30</span>
## [17] <span class="black">A8</span>
## [18] <span class="black">£61</span>
## [19] <span class="black">470m</span>
## [20] <span class="black">-20</span>
## ...
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.

I probably think it's the same problem I had with other websites, do you know where I can find informations about how to extract the query whenever I have a dynamic website?

Comment: Developer Tools and Burp Suite. It takes a bit of work usually.

Comment: Is there a guide about it?

Comment: This code is not working, is throwing the error "Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Timeout was reached"

Comment: That is not a problem of the code, it's a problem of the web site. R can't force websites to be up.

Comment: I've tried on the other machine and it's working fine, sorry. Any idea about what is throwing the error?

Comment: I have no idea what system you're running it on or what network that machine is on. It could be a firewall issue, a network proxy issue or many other things. If Windows, try looking up how to set proxy settings.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is good and `rvest` is working just fine. The problem is that **what you are looking for is not in `url` object**.

If you open that website and use web browser inspecting tool, you will see that all data you want is descendant of `<div id="resultMainOutput">`. Now if you look up source code of this website, you will this (line-breaks added for readability):

```
<div id="resultMainOutput">
    <div class="wait">
       <img src="http://ui.racingpost.com/img/all/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." />
    </div>
</div>
```

Data you want is **loaded dynamically** and `rvest` is not able to cope with that. It can only fetch website source code and retrieve anything that there is without any client-side processing.

The exact same issue was brought up in [rvest-introducing blog post](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/11/24/rvest-easy-web-scraping-with-r/#comment-19108) and here is what package author had to say:

> You have two options for pages like that:
>
> 1. Use the debug console in the web browser to reverse engineer the communications protocol and request the raw data directly from the server.
> 2. Use a package like RSelenium to automate a web browser.

If you don't need to obtain that data repeatedly, or you can accept a bit of manual work in every analysis, the easiest workaround is:

1. Open website in web browser of choice
2. Using web browser inspecting tool, copy **current** website content (entire page or only `<div id="resultMainOutput">` content)
3. Paste that thing into text editor and save it as new file
4. Run analysis on that file

```
> url <- read_html("/tmp/racingpost.html")
> html_nodes(url, ".black")
# {xml_nodeset (56)}
# [1] <span class="black">A9</span>
# [2] <span class="black">Â£61</span>
# [3] <span class="black">470m</span>
# [4] <span class="black">-30</span>
# (skip the rest)
```

As you can see, there are some encoding issues along the way, but they can be solved later on.