# Rvest html_nodes not able to select div.class

Tags: html, r, rvest

I am trying to get all the headlines from the following site:

https://www.montelnews.com/en/

```
my_url <- "https://www.montelnews.com/en/"
```

I noticed all of them have are in a `div` that has the same `class`: featurednewsjs-header

I tried the following but it failed since I am getting an empty `list`:

```
test <- read_html(my_url) %>%
  html_nodes("div.featurednewsjs-header")
```

I noticed though this was giving me an output but it was not at all what I wanted so technically scraping with `rvest` should work:

```
test <- read_html(my_url) %>%
  html_nodes("div.row")
```

All help is appreciated

Comment: I think the headlines are loaded by Javascript dynamically so `rvest` will not work. Try using `RSelenium`

Comment: so if i do something like this it would work:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34473847/rvest-not-recognizing-css-selector